# FFmpeg - how apply filters to input frames

Tags: ffmpeg, input, frame, image-filter

I need to convert thousands of bitmap frames (jpeg individual files) into a video, but I also need to adjust the contrast, gamma and brightness of input frames. Those frames have some quality, but the output of the ffmpeg is darker and less defined, some important shadow details vanish. This is the command used:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v mjpeg_cuvid -framerate 30 -i "_input_frames%04d.jpg" filter=brightness=0.3 -c:v h264_nvenc _video_output.mp4
```

I also try to use the option -tune:film, but it result in error everywhere I place the command.

Answer (score 0):

`filter=brightness=0.3` is not valid.

- You are missing `-vf`.
- There is no filter named *brightness*, but there are several filters that can be used to change brightness such as [eq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq), [colorlevels](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorlevels), [curves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves-1), etc.

Simplified example:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i input%04d.jpg -vf "eq=brightness=0.3,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```